# ¿Por qué no se otorgó automáticamente esta recompensa a una respuesta con 2+ votos?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Hace un tiempo [publiqué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22761/1) una respuesta para la pregunta

[Como puedo saber desde y hacia donde estoy navegando con ngRoute](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22550/como-puedo-saber-desde-y-hacia-donde-estoy-navegando-con-ngroute)

Dicha respuesta es bastante sencilla de entender pero al parecer el OP no solucionó su problema ni tampoco publicó comentarios. Recibí un voto positivo pero no la respuesta aceptada lo cual me pareció raro pues el snippet de código demostraba el problema y daba le daba una solución eficiente.

Unos días después el OP me escribe:

> Gracias por responder @devconcept. Pero no entiendo cómo podría implementar eso con el controlador del template temporal, ¿podrías darme un ejemplo por favor? -Recuerda que mis rutas tienen id.

Básicamente no pudo implementarlo pues su problema es ligeramente diferente al código de mi ejemplo. En el momento que leo el comentario no pude editar y hacer la solución mas aún más comprensible pero cuando pude conseguir algo de tiempo noto que la pregunta tiene 50 puntos de recompensa.

Simplemente hice lo que iba a hacer de todas formas, editar la respuesta e ir agregando más información, editándola:

1. https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22761/2
2. https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22761/3
3. https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/22761/4

Aún así, el OP no pudo entender lo que puse pues usé expresiones regulares y el usó cadenas de caracteres para reproducir mi solución. Le escribí un comentario pero no recibí más feedback.

> @adrianojosue fromRegexp y toRegExp son expresiones regulares. Tu tienes cadenas de caracteres. Fijate en los simbolos / al pricipio y al final. Como lo tienes está bien lo que debes comparar la url completa. Tu estas comparando /news/id y yo estoy comparando http://..../news/id. Ese es el formato de los valores que llega en from y to

De todas formas la recompensa expiró y me extrañó no recibir nada, a pesar de que la respuesta tiene dos votos positivos y es la única respuesta a la pregunta.

Según la ayuda

> Si no otorgas tu recompensa en 7 días (más el periodo de gracia), la respuesta más votada publicada tras el ofrecimiento con una puntuación mínima de 2 recibirá la mitad del importe de la recompensa. Si hay dos respuestas o más que cumplan los criterios y tengan la misma puntuación, la respuesta más antigua se llevará la recompensa. Si no hay ninguna respuesta que cumpla los criterios, la recompensa quedará sin otorgar.

Así que la pregunta es, ¿por qué, si la respuesta cumplía con los requisitos, no recibió al menos la mitad de la recompensa como era de esperarse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema está aqui:

> la respuesta más votada publicada **tras el ofrecimiento** con una puntuación mínima de 2 recibirá la mitad del importe de la recompensa.

Y por lo que dices tu pusiste tu respuesta antes del ofrecimiento de la recompensa.

Comment: Je es cierto. Creo que es algo absurdo porque en teoría si hubiera eliminado mi respuesta y publicado una nueva en la misma pregunta es posible que se hubiera otorgado. Gracias

Comment: Si, yo realmente pienso lo mismo y tendría que ser una puntuación mínima de 2, da igual si se ha respondido antes de la recompensa o después.

Comment: Opino lo mismo @devconcept , esta política debería ser cambiada, ya que la respuesta puede no ser la correcta pero puede ser lo mismo si se ofrece recompensa y alguien responde posteriormente con una respuesta que tal vez no satisface al OP pero tiene una puntuación minina de 2.